# Creating shared_ptr only class with private destructor?

Tags: c++, c++20, shared-ptr

I have a data class that is passed between threads. I would like this class to be a `std::shared_ptr` only class that cannot be destroyed by calling its destructor from outside and so I want the destructor to be private as well. My current solution is

```
template<typename T>
struct DestructorHelper
{
    static void Destroy(void* v) { delete static_cast<T*>(v); }
};

class SharedOnly
{
public:
    SharedOnly(const SharedOnly& other) = delete; // deleted copy constructor
    SharedOnly& operator=(const SharedOnly& other) = delete; // deleted copy assignment operator
    SharedOnly(SharedOnly&& other) = delete; // deleted move constructor
    SharedOnly& operator=(SharedOnly&& other) = delete; // deleted move assignment operator

    static std::shared_ptr<SharedOnly> create()
    {
        auto objPtr = new SharedOnly;
        auto desPtr = &DestructorHelper<SharedOnly>::Destroy;
        std::shared_ptr<SharedOnly> shared(objPtr, desPtr);
        return shared;
    }

private:
    SharedOnly() = default;
    ~SharedOnly() = default;
    friend struct DestructorHelper<SharedOnly>;
};
```

Is there any way I could make this class without the `DestructorHelper`? What I am looking for is an elegant solution to make a `std::shared_ptr` only class so that it can be passed around to different threads and is only destroyed when the last shared pointer pointing to the object is destroyed.

Comment: What do you want to achieve by keeping the destructor private ?

Comment: @wohlstad It is a subclass and the destructor can be called from anywhere in any thread which has access to the shared pointer and that will delete the underlying object. That's why I want to restrict it.

Comment: `I want the destructor to be private as well` why? What is the gain? If something is managed by `shared_ptr` you are implicitly passing destruction responsibility to `shared_ptr` so I do not get what private destructor can improve anything.

Comment: @MarekR I am using a subclass of `QObject` and it has a `deleteLater()` function which I want to disable by hiding the destructor.

Comment: `QObject` and `shared_ptr`? Your question lacks important details and clearly you are overengineering code.

Comment: @MarekR Yes, `QObject` so that it can have signals and slots and `shared_ptr` so that it can be shared easily among different threads and to use `weak_ptr` to hold its reference. I could also use `QSharedPointer` but I prefer `shared_ptr`. I might be overengineering, but this is a central data class in my application and is being used in threads and so I want to be extra careful for its lifetime.

Comment: Irrelevant to cannon, but you'd better derive from `std::enable_shared_from_this<SharedOnly>`, so you could call `SharedOnly::shared_from_this` and `SharedOnly::weak_from_this` on demand. Because you wouldn't want to store `this` anywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a lambda to resolve the destructor access from within `create`:

```
static std::shared_ptr<SharedOnly> create()
{
    return {new SharedOnly, [](SharedOnly *const s) { delete s; }};
}
```

Comment: Upped for pointing out that shared_ptr may itself throw. I think you can go via `unique_ptr` to have the function be a bit more concise while exception safe. Something like this https://wandbox.org/permlink/5eolsIuwQG6SKQBg

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica good idea, I tried it but somehow didn't think of just reusing the deleter for `unique_ptr` as well...

Comment: I do not understand the benefit of using an **intermediary `std::unique_ptr`**?

Comment: @Chaitanya it works just the same, but I don't have a raw owning pointer to worry about and make exception-safe. In fact, I just screwed it up: `std::shared_ptr`'s constructor is specified to `delete` its argument if an exception occurs, so my `try`/`catch` would double-delete... :) Edit: which means that the `unique_ptr` *is* useless after all. Oh well.

Comment: It wasn't useless. It had us looking at contracts for the various constructors, and refining to a minimal elegant implementation.

Answer (score 3):

As you're using share_ptr, that is to say, you're already using c++11 or above, you could put your DestructorHelper to the lambda function.

```cpp
class SharedOnly
{
public:
    SharedOnly(const SharedOnly& other) = delete; // deleted copy constructor
    SharedOnly& operator=(const SharedOnly& other) = delete; // deleted copy assignment operator
    SharedOnly(SharedOnly&& other) = delete; // deleted move constructor
    SharedOnly& operator=(SharedOnly&& other) = delete; // deleted move assignment operator

    static std::shared_ptr<SharedOnly> create()
    {
        auto objPtr = new SharedOnly;
        std::shared_ptr<SharedOnly> shared(objPtr, [](SharedOnly *ptr) {
            delete ptr;
        });
        return shared;
    }

private:
    SharedOnly() = default;
    ~SharedOnly() = default;

};
```